# Pass Enum as an argument in a function

Tags: c#, enums, xna

so I've looked for an answer to this problem in many different places, but I have not found one that works for my situation. I am developing a game with MonoGame (Microsoft XNA) and I'd like to have a class that handles my inputs. Since XInput only has the ability to check if a key is down on a particular frame, I'd like to create my own functions to check if its been pressed, released, or held.

Here is my problem:

```
    public static void getKeyPress(Enum key)
    {
        updated = Keyboard.GetState();
        if (updated.IsKeyDown(/* what can i put here to have key be the 'Keys' enum */))
        {

        }

        if (updated.IsKeyDown(Keys.Space))
        {

        }

    }
```

So, my issue is that I cannot figure out how to use the key Enum that I have as my function's argument. I'm trying to have that be the argument for the IsKeyDown function, which is included in the XNA framework. The IsKeyDown function only accepts something from the Keys enum that is prebuilt with the framework. The second if statement shows the correct usage of the function, with Keys.Space. I'd like to have the getKeyPress function work like this:

```
if (getKeyPress(Keys.Backspace))
{
    //backspace was pressed
}
```

Or, this also would work:

```
if (getKeyPress(Backspace))
{
    //backspace was pressed
}
```

I'm completely lost, if anyone could help me out with this, that'd be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Method(object enum)

Comment: If I am understanding you correctly, you just want to be able to pass `Keys` into your method, then you should be able to fix this with just changing the word `Enum` in your signature to `Keys`. Am I understanding your question correctly?

Comment: I have added an answer, but I am little confused as to which `Keys` enum you are using, you mention XNA framework which as far as I know has `Keys.Back` as the value for Backspace (see [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.input.keys(v=xnagamestudio.40).aspx)) not `Keys.Backspace`

Comment: I don't understand the downvote, what did he do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have understood correctly, you should be able to just change your method signature to specify the type you want to pass in.  In your case, you want the `Keys` enum.

```
public static void getKeyPress(Keys key)
{
    updated = Keyboard.GetState();
    if (updated.IsKeyDown(key))
    {
    }

    if (updated.IsKeyDown(Keys.Space))
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: That worked. I'm still new to dealing with Enum types, thank you very much. I will accept this as an answer when the timer is up.